# Reducing multiple if statements to a table

Tags: python, database

I am translating a kids choose your own adventure book into a python program eg, 'If you choose x go to page y or if you choose a go to page b'

While this program works, by the end of the book there will be over 100 if statements is there any way to create a table that that compares a user input to a list of pages. An example I saw while researching displayed a similar table to this:

```
#this would hold the potential user inputs
[0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0]
[0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

However i am unsure how to implement it

```
#imports the pages of the book from another python file
from Content import *

clrscrn = (chr(27) + "[2J")

def page0():
    print "\n %s" % page1

page0()

#User input loop
while True:
    inp = raw_input(">>> ").lower()

#clears the screen then prints the variable (page) 

if inp == '3':
    print clrscrn
    print '%s' % page3

if inp == '10':
    print clrscrn
    print '%s' % page10

if inp == '5':
    print clrscrn
    print '%s' % page5

if inp == '14':
    print clrscrn
    print '%s' % page14

#quits python
elif inp == 'quit':
    raise SystemExit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference in each `if` statement is which page variable you access. Since you want to get at `page14` if the user enters "14" you can use the dictionary returned by `globals()` to access the page variables in a dynamic way.

So, instead of hundreds of `if` statement, you really don't need any at all. You can use the following lines instead.

```
print clrscrn
print globals()['page' + inp]
```

Comment: Im attempting to implement this with the current code however i am not sure where to add the global variable

Comment: Solved it thankyou! i deleted everything below the input line and added what you suggested, works great!

Answer (score 1):

Define in your head what the inputs and outputs will be.

To me, it seems likely that you will have multiple questions, on different pages. So one input would be the "current page number." That would identify the question.

The other input, of course, would be the user's response. In a binary (yes/no) system, there would always be exactly two possible responses from the user (yes, or no). In a non-binary system, there might be more possible responses.

I'd suggest that you assume non-binary, and further, even if only one question is possibly non-binary, go with that. It helps keep things consistent.

Let's assume, then, that you've got a non-binary system with 100 questions.  Each question appears at the end of a "page." (Maybe it's at the end of a "chapter" or "paragraph" or something. Feel free to replace words.) When the user answers, they are directed to go to a different "page."

So your mapping is going to be "current page + user input -> new page".

The easiest way to implement this in python is with a list of dictionaries. The list index can be the current page. That will identify the question, and the possible responses. The responses (keys in the dictionary) can be text strings. The results (values from the dictionary) will be integers, indicating the new page number. Thus:

```
Pages = [ # List of questions, one per page. Use {} for page with no Q
    {}, # 0
    {}, # 1
    {   
      "yes": 12,
      "no": 16,
    },  # 2
 ]
```

If you want to be a little more efficient, you can store the questions in the same list, using a key like `" q "` which cannot be input by the user (because you will run `.strip()` on the user input, naturally)!

```
{
    " q ": "Do you like pizza?",
    "yes": 12,
    "no": 16,
}
```

If you're feeling really energetic, you can make the dictionaries into a class, with attributes, store the various pages as JSON, etc.